# onMouseOver event doesn't get fired for a Google visualization DataTable

Tags: php, jquery, google-visualization

The `onmouseover` event doesn't get fired for the Google visualization `DataTable`.

```
var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('results'));
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(d);
var cssClassNames = {'hoverTableRow': 'hover-table-row'};

view.setColumns([1,2,3,4,5]);
table.draw(view, {width:1200,'cssClassNames':cssClassNames});

google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', 
    function() {
      $('#results').mouseover(
          function (e) {
            alert('inside');
          });
    });
```

I do have set a view for the table hiding to one column. Can anyone give advise what is wrong with the code?

Here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/7ezfjpc9/

Comment: I'd check and make sure you didn't misspell the results id in your html first. I've totally written stuff like <div id='#results'>This div should have # in id</div> in my markup a bunch of times

Comment: @PandemoniumSyndicateHere is the code http://jsfiddle.net/7ezfjpc9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues :

1. see the [**docs**](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table) :

> The chart is ready for external method calls. If you want to interact
>   with the chart, and call methods after you draw it, **you should set up
>   a listener for this event before you call the draw method**, and call
>   them only after the event was fired.

So what you need is to declare  `google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function() {` *before* `draw()` - then it will work.
See forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/apwaj5oo/**

2. You are lacking jQuery - guess this was a blunder when you created the fiddle :)

---

However, you really dont need to listen for `ready` before you attach the mouseover handler. You can simply use a [**delegated event**](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) :

```js
$('#table_div').on('mouseover', 'table', function (e) {
    alert('inside');
});
```

This will attach the event handler to the `<table>` google visualization injects, even if you declare the handler before visualization actually has injected the `<table>` - another forked version of your fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/1rz9zqo5/**